# How to write directive for to many ng-if condition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, directive

I have a simple form in which I am showing simple text, same text with a Tick and hiding same text based on the `ng-if` conditions. I want to make a directive but i dont know how. I made simple directives but this one seems complicated.

Here is my **html**

```
<ul class="list-unstyled carsure-listing-detail">
    <li ng-if="!button_clicked && !checkboxModel.value1"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value1"> Right B Pillar is Non-Accidented</li>                      
    <li ng-if="button_clicked && checkboxModel.value1"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Right B Pillar is Non-Accidented</li>
    <li ng-if="!button_clicked && checkboxModel.value1"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value1"> Right B Pillar is Non-Accidented</li>
</ul>
```

here is my **controller**

```
var mainControllers = angular.module('mainControllers', []);
mainControllers.controller('StarterController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.checkboxModel = {};
    $scope.button_clicked = false;

    console.log($scope.button_clicked);
    $scope.checksubmit = function () {
        $scope.button_clicked = true;

    }

}]);
```

Any suggestions how can i achieve this same functionality ?

Comment: Pass a callback function that returns boolean value. This way, you will keep your view clean and also make it generic.

Comment: If the 1st and 3rd options are the same, you can combine them in same line:  ng-if="!button_clicked"

Comment: first and third options are not same check carefully

Comment: As I see the only difference is in the condition? 
So for any value of checkboxModel, if the buttonClicked is false, we will show the same input/text ?

Comment: @rajesh can  you atleast show me how to do this ? i am still stuck

Answer (score 0):

Just divide the business logic and the presentation logic.

In controller:

```
$scope.firstItemIsVisible = !button_clicked 
    && ...(you can put more options here)...
    && !checkboxModel.value1;
$scope.secondItemIsVisible = button_clicked 
    && checkboxModel.value1
```

On view:

```
<li ng-if="firstItemIsVisible">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value1">
        Right B Pillar is Non-Accidented
</li>                      
<li ng-if="secondItemIsVisible">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    Right B Pillar is Non-Accidented
</li>
```

The possible case of a directive will look like:

```
<li put-if1="!button_clicked" 
    put-if2="!checkboxModel.value1">
    ...
</li>
```

But it will be redundant and can make you skip one of the equations in some cases.

Comment: i dont want an ngif i want a directive